# Computing how long it takes for something to decrease with differential equations of calculus

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

​When a condenser discharges electricity, the instantaneous rate of change of the voltage is proportional to the voltage in the condenser.
Suppose you have a discharging condenser and the instantaneous rate of change of the voltage is 1/100 of the voltage (in volts per second). How many seconds does it take for the voltage to decrease by 90%?

What I have gotten so far:

v'[x] = instantaneous rate of change of the voltage

v[x] = voltage in the condenser

v'[x] = r v[x]

v[x] = k e^(rx)

I don't fully understand why v[x] = k e^(rx). I just know it is true. How do you solve this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "separable" differential equation.  Using $d$ notation it's

$$\frac{dv}{dx} = r v$$ which separates as

$$\frac{dv}{v} = r \; dx.$$  Integrate both sides:

$$\ln(v) = rx+C$$ where one constant does for both sides.  Exponentiate

$$v = e^{rx+C} = e^Ce^{rx}.$$  Let $k=E^C$ to get

$$  v= ke^{rx}.$$

You are given $r=-1/100$.  Suppose the initial voltage is $A$, then

$$v(0) = A = ke^0 = k,$$ so $k=A.$

You then need to solve $0.1A = Ae^{-x/100}$ for $x$, which is easy since the $A$ cancels.

Comment: you probably mean $A-0.9A = 0.1A=Ae^{-x/100}$

Comment: @mathreadler Yep.  Got a couple other typos to fix, too.

Comment: Where does $ \frac{dv}{dx} =rv $ come from? I usually write $\frac{dy}{dx} $ to show when I take the derivative. Usually after the d notation comes a formula that I am taking the derivative of. It is strange to see that notation out there without a function following it. Can you start the same math problem but write y’(x) = r y(x)? Are these two notations saying the same thing?